# EventBus support in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I would love to see support in Micronaut for a type of **EventBus** mechanics similar to the one that exists in Guava or Spring.

The would be that a bean method annotated with a given annotation i.e (**@Subscribe**)
would be ***automatically registered as a listener*** for events that could be fired via 
an implementation of this EventBus given by Micronaut container.

Additionally optionally it would be cool if this would be handled async maybe using  the equivalent of one elastic I/O executor service.

Thank you,
 Oscar

Comment: This looks like a feature request for Micronaut developers. It would be on-topic at the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues).

Comment: Thank you just created the issue, https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now achieve 90% of what an event bus offers by publishing an event:

```java
class MyEvent { }

class MyBean {
    @Inject 
    ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public void run() {
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new MyEvent());
    }
```

And adding an async event listener:

```java
@Listener
@Async
void myEventListener(MyEvent event) {
    ..
}
```

Other features like filtering etc can be added as necessary at the method level.

Comment: @LuisTrigueiros you can accept the answer if it is useful )